# Debugging error in calling SendMessage - GetLastWin32Error returns different errorcodes

Tags: c#, debugging, winapi

I am trying to use the [SendMessage API](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage) and **debug why some calls seem to fail**. I am starting to think that my original assumption that the API actually can return errors might be where I am going wrong though, which was the route I began with - getting the error code from the call, since something is going south. What I attempted in order to figure out how errors work, was to provide illegal input and see how the API reacts.

If I provide a negative handle, or a handle to a window that does not exist, the call returns false, and a call to `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` then returns **1400** ([invalid window handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385(v=vs.85).aspx#ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE)), which seems correct/expected.

When I then try to use the same boolean check on calling a window that *should* be able to process the message, but does not react to it, I get very different results depending on the context in which the code is executed (5 different scenarios total, repeated numerous times with consistent results), I get 3 different error codes:

1. *Running with debugger attached in Visual Studio - Debug*: Returns the error code **0**.
2. *Running with debugger attached in Visual Studio - Debug*: Returns the error code **0**.
3. *Running from commandline - Debug:* Returns the error code **1150** ([token does not exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx#ERROR_OLD_WIN_VERSION)).
4. *Running from commandline - Release:* Error code gone again, and returns **0**.
5. *Single stepping in VS and then use Immediate Window for error code retrieval - Debug:* Returns the error code **1008** ([newer windows version required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx#ERROR_NO_TOKEN)).
6. *Single stepping in VS and then use Immediate Window for error code retrieval - Release:* I'm unable to get the debugger to attach in that scenario, possibly due to wrongly configured VS debug settings, but I see that as a minor issue compared to the different results I get above.

The only error code above that seems reasonably correct to me is the 5th scenario, with the error code **1008**, because the handle might not be accessible from the calling context, which is the scenario I am trying to debug.

#### Sample code

The code snippet I am testing looks like this:

```
if (!SendMessage(new IntPtr(windowHandleId), WM_COPYDATA, 0, ref copyDataStruct))
{
  var win32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

and SendMessage is defined like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr windowHandle, int message, int wordParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT longParam);
```

#### Where am I going wrong in my setup, and how do I make sure I get the correct error?

I get a meaningful error when using invalid window handles, so my assumption is that setting the error code is supported by the SendMessage API. Is that the assumption that is incorrect though?

Comment: GetLastWin32Error() is not a very good random number generator in this code.  It should only ever be used if a winapi function failed.  You don't know that it failed.  A *FALSE* return from SendMessage() when you send WM_COPYDATA only means that the target window did not process the message, it does not mean that SendMessage failed.  You cannot find out if it failed at all, so remove the code to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant: But why would the result be different depending on how I run it? Or are you suggesting that the error code is always 0, but some of my scenarios have lingering error codes from other code?

Comment: Its value is undefined and can be anything. Don't react to undefined values.

Comment: The traditional mistake with GetLastError() is that programmers assume that it will be 0 when there was no error.  That is not how Windows works, it doesn't set it *at all* if there was no error.  So you just get a random value from whatever *previous* winapi function failed.  You have no idea which, might have happened an hour ago.  And you might never have seen it because Windows internally uses it as well and winapi errors are not necessarily fatal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What do you mean? The method fails (the receiving application does not react), so would GetLastWin32Error not be the correct place to find this error? The return values are not random either, this happens every time I try. It is the same value I get returned for the respective scenario.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am not assuming a value here? I check that the winapi call fails, if it does, then I check GetLastError. And as I just wrote to David, it is the same error over and over, depending on how I execute it.

Comment: You have to read the documentation. Read it carefully. From `SendMessage`: *Return value: The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent.* So you have to go to `WM_COPYDATA` which says: *Return value: If the receiving application processes this message, it should return TRUE; otherwise, it should return FALSE.* Exactly as Hans described. The value returned comes from the recipient and indicates whether or not the message was processed. Nowhere is it stated that `SetLastError` is called. So its value is meaningless.

Comment: Solve your problems by removing `SetLastError = true` from your `DllAttribute` and removing the call to `GetLastWin32Error`.

Comment: `GetLastWin32Error` returns the last Win32 error (duh). Because **`SendMessage` did not raise an error**, it returns whatever the last error **before `SendMessage`** was.

Comment: @immibis: Yes, but I had fault in my test, which led me to conclude that SendMessage actually did raise an error, which sent me way down the wrong track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) says:

> The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent.

In other words, we must refer to the documentation of [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx). It states:

> If the receiving application processes this message, it should return TRUE; otherwise, it should return FALSE.

At no point in this is there any statement concerning `GetLastError`. Which means that you cannot expect `GetLastError` to yield an informative value. You'll just get whatever was passed in the most recent call to `SetLastError`, quite possibly a call made before your call to `SendMessage`.

All that you can infer from a value of false being returned from `SendMessage` is that the receiving application did not process the message.

Comment: So how can I know if an actual error occured, that is what I am trying to figure out? Checking for false was incorrect, but how then?

Comment: If the recipient processed the message, doesn't that indicate that it arrived? Isn't checking the return value fine. What's wrong is trying to call `GetLastWin32Error`.

Comment: I've updated my question again, trying to explain why I am calling it to begin with, and what have led me to believe it makes sense. I hope my assumptions are more clear now.

Comment: I already answered the question you asked. Are you going to keep me here asking question after question with edits.

Comment: I am sorry if my editing has annoyed you, rather than helped you, but we are simply not talking about the same thing here. Even from version 1 I wrote "`and correctly handling any errors when this is called`". It is the errors I am interested in, and I still haven't found out how to handle them. If you can confirm there is no error handling at all for SendMessage, that would be an awesome answer, but my tests just seem to suggest otherwise, which is why I have kept trying. Again, my assumptions might be wrong, because I am (as is probably obvious) by no means an expert in native calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127152/discussion-between-johny-skovdal-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: My bad, I thought that `SendMessage` was the one setting the `1400` error code, which made me conclude that it actually *did* set error codes some times, but that came from an earlier call instead. I know that checking for `false` was the wrong path to go, but initially thought that there where other indicators of when an error had occured, so the GetLastWin32Error still made sense. Thanks for clearing that up! :)